# How to deploy multiple Flask app with static file on Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask

I try to deploy 2 web application with static file which using Flask, but I don't known how to config the Nginx to locate static file of each project.

And this is my configuration on nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 172.24.2.58;

        location /static {
                alias /home/user/project1/app/static;
        }

        location /project1 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /project2 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hosting multiple Flask apps on different sub paths is not trivial, but can be done with e.g. Gunicorn app server.

So for example a Flask app in `/home/user/project1/app/app.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The `index.html` contains just a single image with `url_for` for testing:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='example_image.jpg') }}" />
```

We start the Gunicorn from the projects' folder like this:

```
# Project1 in /home/user/project1/app/
gunicorn --env SCRIPT_NAME=/project1 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app

# Project2 in /home/user/project2/app/
gunicorn --env SCRIPT_NAME=/project2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 app:app
```

So the root URL for the project1 is `http://localhost/project1/`. It will load its `@app.route("/")` endpoint.

And the nginx site config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 172.24.2.58;

        location /project1/static {
                alias /home/user/project1/app/static;
        }
        
        location /project2/static {
                alias /home/user/project2/app/static;
        }        

        location /project1 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/project1;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /project2 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/project2;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

So the static files for project1 will be served from `/home/user/porject1/app/static` at `/project1/static` base URL. Since Gunicorn will map `/project1` path to the root of project1 app, we don't have to change the static file routing in the apps so e.g. `url_for('static', filename='example_image.jpg')` will work in both apps.